# How to install/import libraries in Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode

First time writing C on a Mac.  I am using Xcode.

I complied the .c file, and get an error saying gsl/gsl_math.h file not found.

I know in Cygwin, this is already installed, I don't know about Mac.

So, I came here and downloaded the library. http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

I am having trouble using terminal to install.  What are the commands?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the `-I` include path flag for your library?

Comment: I don't know what -I is.  I read in another posting saying I have to install the command line tools in preference>Downloads.  I am using Xcode 4.4.1